# Execution order of code with continue;?

Tags: c++

I usually work with C#, so please bear with me. Also, the code was written by someone else.

The code essentially outputs some information to a text file, and for some reason, at midnight, the file was only exported with carriage returns and line separators (ie. no actual data).

After debugging it, I noticed that the debugger breaks on a `continue;`, but then anything after that line in the `FOR` loop (in init2) is not being executed.

Due to the complexity of the code, I had to remove most of it. But I've included where all the `FOR` loops are. I just need to know what the CONTINUE is doing that skips where the "important stuff" is being output.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
for ( init1; condition; increment ) {
    for ( init2; condition; increment ) {
        CODE;
        for ( init3; condition; increment ) {
            CODE;

            if (condition) {
                CODE;
            }
            CODE;
        }
        if (condition) continue;  //Always breaks here

        CODE;  //Never breaks here

        if (condition) {  //Never breaks here, so important stuff is not output to file.
            for ( init4; condition; increment ) {
                fprintf_s(fp, "Output important stuff");
            }
            fprintf_s(fp, "\n");
        }
    }
    if (statement) { //This code runs and the following is printed.
        fprintf_s(fp, "----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify that: are you asking *why* compiler discards rest of the loop when it sees a keyword that *instructs* him to do so, or do you want us to tell you why condition, that causes this became true *without* seeing relevant code?

Comment: [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) causes a jump back to the top of the enclosing `for` loop.

Comment: [C#, you say?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I worded the post incorrectly. I understand that `continue` of takes me to the top of the enclosing `for` loop. I was just not seeing why the debugger wasn't breaking in the following line of code.

Comment: It just hit me that it hits `continue`, takes me back to the `for` loop, which then evaluates to `false`. And  the code that follows the `continue` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is your condition inside the if statement. I'm not sure that we can provide you further help if we don't see the actual code.